# Data grid View database

Tags: c#

```
private void buttonsubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    String column1 =(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["RegNo"].Value.ToString());

    CLib.idUpdateTable("Attendence", "Reg_No='"+column1+"'", "No_Present", 
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].ToString(), "No_Days", 
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].ToString(),"Present_percentage",
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].ToString(), "Month" , 
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].ToString());

    IdLoad();     
}
```

I am getting error like this: `Index was out of range. Must //be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`

Comment: am getting error like this: Index was out of range. Must //be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: Please add the error to the question

Comment: On which line do you have the error ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add your error to the question then by using debugging tell us where are you getting the error. Is it in 1st line or the 2nd  line of your code ? as there are lots of code which can get the error.

Comment: So, did you already debug??? What is happening? Where?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to comment/guide if you provide exact place where you are getting this error.

I suspect, the error could be due to index values used to read grid entries . Below code might help you to ignore the exception, I strongly suggest put debug point and identify what values your DataGrid contains. Use column names(if possible) instead of indexes to read DataGrid Values.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count > 6)
{
     CLib.idUpdateTable("Attendence", "Reg_No='"+column1+"'","No_Present",
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].ToString(), "No_Days",
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].ToString(), "Present_percentage",
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].ToString(), "Month",
        dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].ToString());
}
```